# How to calculate the mean and standard deviation of combined series?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, standard-deviation

A company produces two products. It sells the product P1 per month and the product P2 per season. The revenue of the product P1 over one year (with monthly frequency) is stored in A.

```
A = [1000 1020 1030 903 807 1005 1014 1090 1020 1080 1045 999]
```

The revenue of the product P2 over one year with seasonal frequency is stored in B.

```
B = [150 170 130 109]
```

The company is interested to know the overall mean and standard deviation for its total revenue.
I think the basic approach is to calculate the total revenue per month as follows:

```
New = [1000+150/3, 1020+150/3, 1030+150/3, 903+170/3,807+170/3,
 1005+170/3,1014+130/3, 1090+130/3, 1020+130/3, 1080+109/3, 1045+109/3, 999+109/3]
```

and then calculate the mean and std of the new income vector.
Is it okay?

As a more general question, let's say we don't have access to the data of A and B, but we know the mean and std of A and B. How can we calculate the mean and std of the total revenue?

Comment: As a general proposition--and one that likely applies to two product streams, which likely are correlated--you don't have enough information to compute the SD of the total revenue.  An estimate of the covariance or the correlation (or the equivalent) would supply what you need.

Comment: Shouldn't you divide the seasonal revenue for the product P2 by 3 before adding it to the monthly revenue of the product P1?

Comment: Yes I should. Thanks.